# SQL Server studio Function variable scope error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, stored-functions

I was trying to use a function as an exercise wherein I have 2 string delimited by `;` (example: '1;22;333;444;;5555;666') and another string in the same format.

I want to check that in case of large data set, both strings have same elements in it

Example

```
@string1 : 'a','b','c' 
@string2 : 'a','g','c'
```

In this case, I want the answer as false as B and C were not in the second string.

Example2

```
@string1 : 'a','b','c' 
@string2 : 'a','b','c'
```

In this case the answer will be true.

So far I am doing something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnSplit(
    @sInputList VARCHAR(8000), -- List of delimited items
    @sDelimiter VARCHAR(8000) = ',' -- delimiter that separates items
    ) 
RETURNS @List TABLE (item VARCHAR(8000))
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sItem VARCHAR(8000)

    WHILE CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter, @sInputList, 0) <> 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT
            @sItem = RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@sInputList, 1, CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter, @sInputList, 0) - 1))),
            @sInputList = RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@sInputList, CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter, @sInputList, 0) + LEN(@sDelimiter), LEN(@sInputList))))

        IF LEN(@sItem) > 0
            INSERT INTO @List 
                SELECT @sItem
    END

    IF LEN(@sInputList) > 0
        INSERT INTO @List 
            SELECT @sInputList -- Put the last item in
    RETURN
END
GO

select * from dbo.fnSplit('1;22;333;444;;5555;666', ';')
```

which results in

```
1
22
333
444
5555
666
```

And then I have another function which is causing error:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnSplitFinal(
    @sInputList VARCHAR(8000) -- List of delimited items (source string) 
  ,  @sInputList2 VARCHAR(8000) -- List of delimited items2(target string) 

  , @sDelimiter VARCHAR(8000) = ','  -- delimiter that separates items source 
  , @sDelimiter2 VARCHAR(8000) = ',' -- delimiter that separates items target
) RETURNS  Integer 

BEGIN
DECLARE @list1 TABLE (item VARCHAR(8000));
DECLARE @list2 TABLE (item VARCHAR(8000));
DECLARE @listFinal TABLE (item VARCHAR(8000), item2 Varchar(8000), Istrue varchar(50)) ;

--source 
Insert Into @list1 (Item) 
select * from master.dbo.fnSplit(@sInputList, ';')

--target
Insert Into @list2 (Item)  
select * from Master.dbo.fnSplit(@sInputList2,';')

--final 
insert Into @listFinal (Item, item2, istrue)
select a.item , b.item,
Case 
    when a.item = b.item then 'true'
    when a.item != b.item then 'false' 
    when a.item is not NULL and b.item is NULL then 'falseNULL'
else 'cc'
end as Istrue
from @list1 --> error here, out of scope?  
left Join @list2 
    on @list1.item = List2.item
Declare @result Integer 

select @result = (select count(*) from @listFinal where isTrue !="true" ) 

RETURN @result 
END
GO
```

this is showing error "Must declare a scalar variable @list1 "

Any help is valuable and will lead to a new learning!

Comment: what is a and b aliases in your error query?

Comment: I would strongly suggest you toss that current split function in the trash can. There are many options that are much better for splitting strings than using a while loop. Here are several of them. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.fnSplitFinal(
    @sInputList VARCHAR(8000) -- List of delimited items (source string) 
  ,  @sInputList2 VARCHAR(8000) -- List of delimited items2(target string) 

  , @sDelimiter VARCHAR(8000) = ','  -- delimiter that separates items source 
  , @sDelimiter2 VARCHAR(8000) = ',' -- delimiter that separates items target
 ) RETURNS Integer 

BEGIN
DECLARE @list1 TABLE (item VARCHAR(8000));
DECLARE @list2 TABLE (item VARCHAR(8000));
DECLARE @result INT

--source 
Insert Into @list1 (Item) 
select * from dbo.fnSplit(@sInputList, @sDelimiter)

--target
Insert Into @list2 (Item)  
select * from dbo.fnSplit(@sInputList2,@sDelimiter2)

--final 
SELECT @result = COUNT(*)
FROM @list1
WHERE item NOT IN
      (
          SELECT item FROM @list2
      );

RETURN @result 
END
GO
```

I put your @delimiter parameters into the function, added a declaration for the @result variable, and simplified the final query.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the support guys. I have finally figured this one out. Here is my solution to the problem.

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.fnSplitFinal(
    @sInputList VARCHAR(8000) -- List of delimited items (source string) 
  ,  @sInputList2 VARCHAR(8000) -- List of delimited items2(target string) 

  , @sDelimiter VARCHAR(8000) = ','  -- delimiter that separates items source 
  , @sDelimiter2 VARCHAR(8000) = ',' -- delimiter that separates items target
) RETURNS   @FinalResult TABLE (isTrue VARCHAR(8000), Missing varchar(2000))


BEGIN
DECLARE @list1 TABLE (item VARCHAR(8000));
DECLARE @list2 TABLE (item VARCHAR(8000));
DECLARE @listFinal TABLE (item VARCHAR(8000), item2 Varchar(8000), Istrue varchar(50)) ;

--source 
Insert Into @list1 (Item) 
select * from master.dbo.fnSplit(@sInputList, ';')

--target
Insert Into @list2 (Item)  
select * from Master.dbo.fnSplit(@sInputList2,';')

--final 
insert Into @listFinal (Item, item2, istrue)
select a.item , b.item,
Case 
    when ltrim(rtrim(a.item)) = ltrim(rtrim(b.item)) then 'true'  -- Matching Value found 
    when ltrim(rtrim(a.item)) !=ltrim(rtrim(b.item)) then 'false' -- There is a mismatch in the value // not able to join also. 
    when a.item is not NULL and b.item is NULL then a.item+' is missing in the target' 
    When b.item is NOT NULL and A.item is NULL then b.item+' in target, not in source' 
else 'CheckAgain'
end as Istrue
from @list1 a
left Join @list2 b 
    on a.item = b.item

DECLARE @error VARCHAR(8000) 
SELECT @error = COALESCE(@error + ', ', '') + istrue 
FROM @listFinal where istrue !='True'


Declare @result Integer 
select @result = (select count(*) from  @listFinal where Istrue != 'True') 

 IF @result > 0
  INSERT INTO @FinalResult(isTrue,Missing) SELECT 'false',@error --isTrue from @listFinal where Istrue!='true'

 IF @result = 0
  INSERT INTO @FinalResult(isTrue,Missing) SELECT 'True','NULL'

RETURN  
END
GO
```

Keeping the fnsplit as it is.

Here is the screencast of the result. [image]

thanks!